# Why is darker skin a better defense against sun than lighter skin?

Tags: human-biology

We know from physics that the colour of something comes from the light it reflects.

Dark/Black objects absorb most light while light/white objects reflect most light.

Sunburn is the absorbance of too much light and is bad for your skin's health suggesting that absorbance of light is bad for you.

So why is darker skin better than lighter skin for high sun intesity living conditions? Logically darker skin should absorb more light (and so energy) while lighter skin should reflect most light (and energy).

Comment: I have realised there is a similiar question to my one already existing. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Within stackexchange? please give a link to that possible-duplicate. (To do that; copy the URL and paste in comment). If that is an exact duplicate; then it could be deleted; but please wait for moderator-intervention. If it is NOT an exact-duplicate then point it out what different thing you're looking for.